# Privacy of views with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm relatively new to Angular (using 1.5.x) and I'd like to ask for a good approach regarding maintaining the privacy of views that are supposed to be loaded only after a previous authentication has been passed:

Currently I'm developing an app with Express, using passport, the workflow is very similar to what is described here:

https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/

https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-2/

with some irrelevant differences regarding app structure my concern is, if it's possible while maintaining good practices "angular-wise" to hide client code that is not supposed to be viewed in any form before previous authentication has happened.

As example, suppose I have a view with a table to list the data coming from db, and I'm listing projects, in the layout you could already see things like the headers of the table that would list the name of the fields in the db table, or maybe some other pieces of data that should be restricted until a user is logged in.

Please keep in mind, that if possible there should be more robust ways than setting variables in the client controller/services or app config to switch what is hidden or not, since these things can be relatively easy passed by someone in the client-side by making changes in its app state. I would prefer to not load from the server anything at all, including views/partials that are part of the restricted zones of the page.

What would be a good example of protecting parts of the view that only should be received in the client after successful authentication?

Comment: In general terms for single-page applications, you probably shouldn't have anything sensitive in your views, so that if they were accessed, it wouldn't matter, since there's nothing but general page structure. That said, it should be possible to use an express route to serve up your files with `res.sendFile()` and a directory with your views that you wish to keep private.

Comment: Thanks @BrandonAnzaldi, ok I could do something like that with express, how would that match from the angular side? with the app routing.

Comment: Well, you'll need to adjust where you're loading the views from. So say you already have a static content directory via `express.static()`, you could create a route that accepts a parameter (e.g. `app.get('/ng-views/:filename', function (req, res) { ... });` (Be careful. I don't remember exactly how express handles routes, so you might want to sanitize the parameter to protect yourself from directory traversal attacks. (Strip double dots, etc.) ) And then `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/protected/views/' + req.params.filename)`. Like I said, be careful with this. There are probably safer ways.